# 2.4 GHz chip antenna layout

Tags: rf, antenna, wifi

I am am new to RF design and I need to place a chip antenna due to space limitations. The only antenna that is easily available to me has a very weird layout.

There is no physical connection from the feedline to the antenna and also the dimensions of this gap are not clearly mentioned. Can anyone please explain what is going on in this layout?

The [link of the datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Huaxin-S-T-RFECA3216060A1T_C127620.pdf).

[image: Recommended PCB layout]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! "There is no physical connection from the feedline to the antenna". I'm confused by your statement. The feed appears to be connected to the right side of the chip antenna in this layout example.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel I am excited to be here and thank you for your reply. If you look at the upper image you will see that feedline goes vertically down and then there is a break. The antenna terminal on the right side is electrically connected to ground. I have never seen anything like this. Usually for chip antennas one side is NC and the other is connected directly to the feedline through a 50 Ohm line.

Comment: That does look strange.  If the gap were important, I'd expect dimensions.  The stub (the connection from feed and antenna to ground) has dimensions.  That weird gap in the feedline is just ignored.

Comment: I think you have just two choices: ask the manufacturer what they meant to say, or use an antenna with better documentation.

Comment: @SaadSaif thanks, missed that!

Comment: Guys, Thank you so much for your responses. Yes, the issue is that the gap is not well explained it might also be a place to place an impedance matching component. Anyways I decided to go with MIFA type PCB trace antenna. The chip I am using has two antenna outputs and I have only space for one MIFA that's why I wanted to use chip antennas.

Answer (score 1):

That is a filter.  It's a stub filter.  The length of the trace is tuned a multiple of the wavelength of interest an then shorted to the ground plane.

[Stub Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stub_(electronics)#Stub_matching)

[image: stub image]

They come in all shapes and sizes

[image]

Here are some that show the non-connected nature of some styles:
http://home.sandiego.edu/~ekim/e194rfs01/filterek.pdf
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately the datasheet does not mention the dimensions of the gap so I cannot replicate it in my design.